# How to group by most occurrence item in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I wrote the following query:

```sql
SELECT i.* FROM items i
    JOIN order_details od ON od.item_id = i.item_id
```

and got the following result:

```
ITEM_ID NAME    DESCRIPTION IMAGE_URL             PRICE
------- ------- ----------- --------------------- -----
1       Apple   (null)      http://www.apple.com    200
1       Apple   (null)      http://www.apple.com    200
2       Orange  (null)      http://www.orange.com   200
3       Banana  (null)      http://www.banana.com   200
3       Banana  (null)      http://www.banana.com   200
3       Banana  (null)      http://www.banana.com   200
4       Item-4  (null)      http://www.banana.com   200
4       Item-4  (null)      http://www.banana.com   200
5       Item-5  (null)      http://www.banana.com   200
6       Item-6  (null)      http://www.banana.com   200
```

And I need the following results which are sorted by most occurrence:

```
NAME    PRICE
------- -----
Banana    200
Apple     200
Item-4    200
Orange    200
Item-5    200
```

I've tried below query and it does not work.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT i.name, i.price FROM items i
    JOIN order_details od ON od.item_id = i.item_id
GROUP BY i.item_id
WHERE count(*) DESC;
```

Comment: Whether or not this is homework, please _delete_ the images from your question and instead include only _text_.

Comment: I'm sorry for lacking that awareness. This is not homework. I'm just trying to figure out the result I want on paper.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `ORDER BY`, not `WHERE`:

```
SELECT i.item_id, i.name, i.price
FROM items i
INNER JOIN order_details od
     ON od.item_id = i.item_id
GROUP BY i.item_id, i.name, i.price
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

Note that all unaggregated columns in the `SELECT` need to be in the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Thanks for you explaination. But it gives this error: `00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"` .

Comment: @JonathanLivingStone Gordon seemed to have a (rare) typo in his answer.  Try it again (note: his original answer might have run on Postgres or MySQL).

Comment: Thank you very much. It works. I really appreciate that.

Comment: @JonathanLivingStone . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted the answer?